# Ember Data: Change belongsTo parent ID sent to the server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Saving this model:

```
  export default DS.Model.extend({
      type: DS.attr('string'),
      primary: DS.attr('boolean'),
      address: DS.attr('string'),
      address2: DS.attr('string'),
      city: DS.attr('string'),
      state: DS.attr('string'),
      postal: DS.attr('string'),
      customer: DS.belongsTo('customer')
   });
```

Using this route:

```
   3 export default Ember.Route.extend({
   4   model() {
   5     return this.store.createRecord('customer-address', {
   6       customer: this.modelFor('customers/show')
   7     });
   8   },
   9   actions: {
  10     save() {
  11       var model = this.modelFor('customer-addresses/new');
  12       model.save().then(() => {
  13         this.transitionTo('customer-addresses');
  14       });
  15     },
  16     cancel() {
  17       this.transitionTo('customer-addresses');
  18     }
  19   }
  20 });
```

Params are sent to my backend like this:

```
Parameters: %{"customer_address" => %{"address" => nil, "address2" => nil, "city" => nil, "customer" => "23", "postal" => nil, "primary" => false, "state" => nil, "type" => ""}}
```

`customer` needs to be `customer_id` (a la Rails) as customer hasMany customer_addresses.

UPDATE:  Here's my serializer

```
   1 import config from '../config/environment';
   2 import DS from 'ember-data';
   3 import Ember from 'ember';
   4
   5 var serializer;
   6 if (config.environment === 'test') {
   7   serializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({});
   8 } else {
   9   serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  10     keyForAttribute: function(attr, method) {
  11       return Ember.String.underscore(attr);
  12     },
  13     payloadKeyFromModelName: function(modelName) {
  14       return Ember.String.underscore(modelName);
  15     },
  16   });
  17 }
  18
  19 export default serializer;
```

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: @andorov Whoops, that would be handy to include.  I updated the OP with the serializer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `keyForRelationship` on your serializer (see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_keyForRelationship)).

```
keyForRelationship: function(key, relationship, method) {
     return Ember.String.underscore(key) + '_id';
}
```

If you are using Rails specifically I would look the Ember Data Active Model Adapter/Serializer, which has been extracted into an addon [here](https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter).

Comment: Worked perfectly - Thanks!.  I'm using Phoenix.